# SQL - How to run a SELECT for a table of tables without a loop

Tags: sql, select

I have the following tables:

```
People:
ID, Name, address, etc.
```

and

```
Phone:
ID, phoneNumber, ..., people.ID
```

Basically the relationship between `People:Phone is 1:N`.

I need to get a list of all the phone numbers for people within a subcategory. So for example I want:

```
Bob, 555-1234, programmer
Bob, 555-2222, programmer
John, 555-2322, SQL expert
...
```

The easy solution is to do a loop such that:

```
SELECT ID, name, ... FROM people WHERE subcategory IN (1, 5, 9, ...);
```

And then I can do a loop:

```
for(eachPerson)
  SELECT phoneNumber FROM phone WHERE people.ID = eachPerson.ID
```

And then combine all the data. But that's really terrible.

Alternatively I can do `LEFT JOIN` and include a `GROUPED BY` clause and this would push all the data into one massive table. My concern is that although this should be more performant the result set will contain a lot of repetitive and useless data. Is there a better way or is this my only option?

I'm also limited to ANSI-SQL.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` only if you want rows in TableA that **don't** have rows in TableB - otherwise, stick with a regular `INNER JOIN`.  Why do you think you need a `GROUP BY`?  You want all the phone numbers, right?  A `JOIN` will (almost certainly) be more efficient that umpteen trips to the db in a loop - the optimizer is your friend, don't try to subvert it.  You will probably want an `ORDER BY` on a joined statement though, to make sure all of a person's records are listed together.

Comment: I don't understand what “repetitive and useless data” you are talking about; do you mean the repeated “Bob”s in the example? You said “I want” that. Please clarify.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I don't want an inner join because it's possible that someone within a subcategory doesn't have a phone number. In this case we still want to include them. And you're right about the GROUP BY, I ended up doing ORDER BY on multiple columns

Comment: @DourHighArch Yes. The example is a bit too simple, but imagine that the data includes more than just the name of the person, but also their address, etc. Basically at least another 10 columns of additional data that's replicated several times over for each phone number they have. Also in the example above most people will generally have 1-2 phone numbers, but in my real database the average is much higher, with the equivalent of 100 phones being pretty standard (in my real database we're dealing with other types of data sets). And I need to grab more than just one column from the phone.

Comment: ...If you're planning on grabbing from more than one table in your loop, it's definitely going to be far more performant to do this in the db.  The problem you're going to end up with, though, is if there are several tables with multiple rows - you're going to end up with several "duplicates" from the Cartesian product.  You say you're limited to ANSI SQL - what about the application that's accessing this data?  Is using an ORM an option?  This would somewhat abstract this part; some of the rows would be gotten through joins and some as individual loops.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse It's not the abstraction that worries me, it's the size of the duplicated data and performance. This could be over fairly large data sets. At this point I'm pretty sure I just have to accept that this is the way it is...